# How to remove the bottom label and the border line in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WFME.png)

Here's my current code solution:

```
[enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: please add the code you tried to your question, also please dont post it as an image since they might get removed and are harder to search through

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I have already resolved my issue. :)